# Button outside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Here is the complete code on which I have problem.

On clicking the but_OK button , the UpdateProgress panel does not show up. However if I put the "dmgConfirm" DIV inside the UpdatePanel , UpdateProgress panel. How to make the UpdateProgress panel showup keeping the  But_OK outside UpdatePanel ?

```
<%@ Page Title="Test Jquery" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestJquery.aspx.cs" Inherits="EluxDamageClaims.TestJquery"  %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress"
    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"
    runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>           

    <div class ="divProgressBarBack" >
    </div>
      <div class ="divProgressBar">
           <img alt="progress" src="images/ajax_loading.gif"/>
           <h1> Processing...  </h1>
    </div>      
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate >


        <asp:Button Text="Make Visible" ID ="btnMakeVisible" runat="server" OnClick="btnMakeVisible_Click" />
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl" Visible ="false" >
```

Dialog

```
<!-- ui-dialog -->
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

```
 <input id="hbtnConfirm" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="openModalDiv('dmgConfirm');" />


            </asp:Panel>
```

```
 <div id="dmgConfirm" title="Damage Claim Confirm " >
        <b> Please confirm your submission ?. You cannot undo this operation.</b><br /><br />

       <table>
           <tr> <td><asp:Button ID="but_OK"  runat="server" Text="Confirm" OnClick="but_OK_Click"  />   </td>
               <td> <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript: closeModalDiv('dmgConfirm');" /></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    <br />
     </div> 
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: remember that a button triggers a PostBack so you may want to use some  client side javascript also what is your update panels `UpdateMode` set to? 
I would set it to `UpdateMode="Conditional"` in your aspx file or code behind also call / issue and explicit `UpdatePanel.UpDate();`

Comment: Could you please show with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to mention trigger for the button- let it even be anywhere in the page- Still it will trigger the UpdteProgress Panel content.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
........
........
<Triggers> <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="but_OK" EventName="Click" /> 
</Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I do have it set. Not sure why it din't copy that code when I pasted above. Also it will trigger...the posback and does the required task in background. But it does not show the progress indicator

Comment: Try adding Some delay in PageLoad (Temporarily For test purpose only) ..  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); (Sleep for  Sec)

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Working Code FYR (Click on "Confirm")

ASPX:

```
 <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress"
        AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" 
        runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="divProgressBarBack">
            </div>
            <div class="divProgressBar">
                //<img alt="progress" src="images/ajax_loading.gif" />
                <h1>Processing...  </h1>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>


            <asp:Button Text="Make Visible" ID="btnMakeVisible" runat="server"  />
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl" Visible="false">
                <input id="hbtnConfirm" type="button" value="Submit onclick="openModalDiv('dmgConfirm');" />


            </asp:Panel>
            <div id="dmgConfirm" title="Damage Claim Confirm ">
                <b>Please confirm your submission ?. You cannot undo this operation.</b><br />
                <br />

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript: closeModalDiv('dmgConfirm');" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="but_OK" runat="server" Text="Confirm" OnClick="but_OK_Click"  />
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void but_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Update();

    }
```

Comment: UpdateProgress control ONLY is not enabled for postback caused by an external trigger of the UpdatePanel.It is by design of this property AssociatedUpdatePanelID.The Implementation of enabling the UpdateProgress control is done by moving through the control hierarchy in UpdatePanel control identified via AssociatedUpdatePanelID to find a match for the control that causes the actual postback. Since, the external triggers will not be present in the hierarchy it will not enable the UpdateProgress.
http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETAJAX/125_Using_UpdateProgress_Control_Effectively.aspx